# Can someone recommend a capture card that will work with Ubuntu 64bit, XBMC, that I can buy in the US

Tags: video, xbmc

I am wanting to add a tv capture card that records over the air antenna channels in the US that will work with Ubuntu 64 bit and XBMC?

I would like add it to my XBMC system that I have hooked up to my tv so that I can record tv shows and such.

I have looked at other post and can't seem to find the correct info on the hardware to use and a place to get it. I am thinking someone like new egg or tiger direct online to get the hardware. also will I have to change my video card or add memory to make this work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 AMD (64-bit OS) running mythbuntu .26 on an old pentium core duo as my mythtv backend (PVR and file server), 2 HDhomerun Dual OTA tuner boxes (attaches to network via ethernet), 2 Antennas Direct DB4e, XBMC Frodo (with Live-TV) running on various XBMC clients (Laptops, Desktops, Zotac ID84, raspberry Pi, latest LG Android Nexus phones)

I use the cmyth pvr plugin in XBMC to connect my XBMC clients to the mythtv backend.

Works great!